# How can I serve HTML files for development using maven?

Tags: maven-3, httpserver, web-development-server

I'm working on a scala app (building with maven) where the UI is html and javascript and the back end is a REST API. For deployment, the html/javascript will just get thrown into nginx as static resources, but for development I just want something that serves up the files from local disk. Other teams use gulp-connect for this, but I'm hoping to avoid adding a second build tool (i.e., gulp) to my stack if I can avoid it.

What are my options for going about this? I see there's an nginx plugin for maven, but it's poorly documented. NanoHttpd seems promising, but it looks like I'd have to write my own maven plugin.

Comment: Just for clarification: Do you need the full frontend stack with grunt/gulp/webpack jobs or just a way to display the frontend while you work on the backend?

Comment: Just a way to display the frontend. What I'm actually trying to accomplish is replicating gulp's connect task without having to install node, npm, and gulp, thereby adding an entirely separate build system just to develop on a fairly simple web ui.